# Income tax India change of form for defective return

Tags: income-tax, india

I have filed a Income tax return with ITR4 and received a communication about defective return asking to fill balance sheet and profit and loss account. 
I think I can file ITR1 or ITR2 instead of the lengthy ITR4. Can I still change the form and file a revised return with ITR1 or ITR2

Answer (score 1):

Generally revisions are to be submitted in the same form as the Original. i.e. in your case ITR4.

However, If you were originally required to only file ITR 1 / 2 and have filed a ITR 4 in error, then yes you can file the revised return in a different form.